# Complex mySQL query using DISTINCT and COUNT to return results

Tags: mysql

This should be simple but I'm struggling with this query.

My first query:

```
( SELECT DISTINCT(firstdaytaken) AS dates, stid FROM tmp_student_pages )
```

returns

```
....dates......|.....stid

2014-02-19.....|.........1

2014-02-22.....|.........2

2014-02-22.....|.........3
```

I'd like ONE complete query to return the DISTINCT dates AND the COUNT of the EACH

Something like

```
unique dates...|.....tot experiences
______________________________

2014-02-19.......|...........1

2014-02-22.......|...........2
```

Thanks in advance - already spent too many hours on trying to get a solution
This is as far as I have gotten - with the incorrect results

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(newdates)),newdates
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT(dates) AS newdates
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT(firstdaytaken) AS dates, stid FROM tmp_student_pages) d ) f
GROUP BY newdates
```

***NOTE**
I've added a link to a graphic of the database table below - hope that helps.

http://www.quizzicle.com/examples/tmp_student_pages.gif

Comment: Please include data, as well as sample of requested result, in order to make it easier to help you.

Comment: Sorry - first time posting here - will do if anyone is unable to help and also for any future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want a `group by` query with `count`.

```
SELECT firstdaytaken, count(stid) FROM tmp_student_pages
group by firstdaytaken;
```

Comment: It's close but here's the result:

firstdaytaken......count(stid)
2014-02-19.............22
2014-02-22.............43

Comment: It's close but here's the result:

firstdaytaken......count(stid)
2014-02-19.............22
2014-02-22.............43

See the tmp_student_pages table includes each page of a course experienced by a student - with each page row including a stid column AND a datetime(firstdaytaken) column.

What I need to retrieve from the tmp_student_pages table is the DISTINCT firstdaytaken AND the number of students(stid) who first experienced the course on that day.

I'll try to edit the question and include the tmp_student_pages table for reference.

Comment: GOT IT - 

Slight adjustment of the query above provided the result.

SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT (
stid
) ) , firstdaytaken
FROM tmp_student_pages
GROUP BY firstdaytaken
LIMIT 0 , 30

MANY THANKS